# how to make this code do select & sort in descending order

Tags: java, search

// here is the code for select and sort and it is in ascending order

```
for (int i = 0; i< arr.length -1; i++)
    int minIndex = i;
    for(int k = i + 1; k< arr.length; k++){
        if(arr[k] < arr [minIndex]){
           minIndex = k;
        }
     }
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
    arr[minIndex] = temp;

}
```

It is in ascending order but I want it to be in descending order

Comment: well what do you think you should do?

Comment: I was thinking of doing: arr[k] > arr[minIndex]

Comment: Hint: have a look at `i++`

Comment: @Maggie And did it work?

Comment: BTW, there is a bug with `if(arr[k] < arr [minIndex]);` - no semicolon is needed

Comment: @Scary Wombat Thank you I fixed the mistake. Do i do something like this : for( int i = arr.length - 1; int i > 0; i--)

Comment: First, check your curly brackets they are not correctly placed.

Comment: @Maggie No the same type of loop should be OK

Comment: @DanishAmjad   for (int i = 0; i< arr.length -1; i++)
    int minIndex = i;
    for(int k = i + 1; k< arr.length; k++){
        if(arr[k] < arr [minIndex]){
           minIndex = k;
        }
     
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[minIndex];
    arr[minIndex] = temp;

}

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i< arr.length -1; i++) {` - need opening curly brace here

Comment: BTW in Java you can sort an Array using `Arrays.sort` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[]) though that looks like homework so you may just have to implement the sorting algorithm

Comment: @Maggie Please update it in your code. It's hard to read here.

Comment: All in all, the `if` within the nested loops will find the smallest `int` beginning at pos `i`, which means your sorting starts with the smallest at index `0`, second smallest at index `1`. You pretty much loop over the array to identify the smallest item. All you have to do here (after the syntax erros are solved) is to identify the biggest number instead of the smallest and you´ll have it sorted descending.

Comment: You need to be making the `minIndex = k` if  `arr[k]` is greater than `arr[minIndex]` not the other way around, if you want `arr` to be in descending order.

Change the line `if(arr[k] < arr[minIndex]){` to `if(arr[k] > arr[minIndex]){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    int maxIndex = i;
    for (int k = i + 1; k < arr.length; k++) {
        if (arr[k] > arr[maxIndex]) {
            maxIndex = k;
        }
    }
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[maxIndex];
    arr[maxIndex] = temp;
}
```

Just change the `arr[k] < arr[minIndex]` to `arr[k] > arr[maxIndex]` in the second loop.